# Unable to getJSON after generating url through function

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get the current local weather information through weather API. Here is my code

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function generateUrl() {
    var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    var city = "PUNE,IN";
    var units = "&units=metric";
    var appid = "&APPID=**************************"
    var cb = "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    
    return (api + city + units+ appid + cb);
}

$.getJSON(generateUrl(), function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(id, val) {
        //document.write(val);
        //document.getElementById('ModifyMe').innerHTML = '<a id ="'+id+'">'+val+'</a>';
        $("div").append(val + " ");
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id = 'ModifyMe'><div>
```

My question: How do i get the  **JSON** file from url generated by **generateUrl()**?

Comment: You shouldn't put valid API keys in your snippets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>    var cb = "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
> ```

You need to let jQuery generate the callback function name.

```
var cb = "&callback=?";
```